# Media queries: not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using webpack and less preprocessor. Also I include `media.less` file at the bottom of `main.less`. The problem is all styles inside `@media` tags are ignored.

**CSS code:**

```
@media all and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  body {
    background-color: black; //ignored, but if put it outside @media tag - it works
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ......
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        ......
    </body>
</html>
```

**webpackConfig.js:**

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'autoprefixer', 'less'] },
    ..................
  ]
},
.....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`min/max-device-width` are [**deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-width)

> **Deprecated**
>
> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible;
>   see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your
>   decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time

---

Instead of using

```
@media all and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px)
```

Use only

```
@media all and (min-width : 414px) and (max-width : 736px)
```

---

**WHY?**

#### [`min/max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#width)

> The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of
>   the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the
>   width of the page box on a printer).

#### [`min/max-device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-width)

> Determines whether the output device is a grid device or a bitmap
>   device.  If the device is grid-based (such as a TTY terminal or a
>   phone display with only one font), the value is 1.  Otherwise it is
>   zero.

Comment: I want it works on both:  mobiles & browsers. Is there any way to use both, like `(min-device-width : 414px) and (min-width : 414px)`?

Comment: `(min-width)` it will work on mobile and desktops,  see Documentation for both [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#width) and [`device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-width)