# different stylesheets for different screen widths

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to use different stylesheets for different screen `widths` (before and after `700px`).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media700.css' media="screen and (max-device-width:700px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media1366.css' media="screen and (min-device-width:701px)">
```

Doesn't work. `media1366` is always overwriting `media700`.

Comment: Should work fine. Please add a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` of your device is larger than `700px`, therefore

```
max-device-width: 700px
```

is not true and

```
min-device-width: 701px
```

is true, therefore the behavior you experience is actually expected.

The two rules cannot override each-other, as they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: But if I resize browser window, for example on 500px, `and reload the page', media700` should be used, shouldn't it ?

Comment: No, that is window width. Your media query relies on device width. If you intend to query by window width, use min-width and max-width instead of min-device-width and max-device-width, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change the order and delete the `device` word

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media1366.css' media="screen and (min-width:701px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media700.css' media="screen and (max-width:700px)">
```

See more info on this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107486/media-queries-not-working/33107576#33107576)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write media queries in sequence Higher Size to Lower Size, so in your case the files should be includes in sequence from Higher 701px to Lower 700px.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media1366.css' media="screen and (min-device-width:701px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media700.css' media="screen and (max-device-width:700px)">
```